# how can i update recyclerview when app is working?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

I am storing the data entered in the first tab of the TabLayout in a Room database. Then, when switching to the second tab, I want the data to be directly displayed in the RecyclerView. However, when I restart the application, the data is visible. I suspect there is an issue with the lifecycle of the fragments, but I haven't been able to resolve it.Help?

Main Activity:

```
import ..

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        viewPager2 = binding.viewPager;
        tabLayout = binding.tabLayout;
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_text_1));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_text_2));

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AddFragment:

```
import ..

public class addFragment extends Fragment {
    FragmentAddBinding binding;
    PeopleDao dao;
    Database db;
    private final CompositeDisposable mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    public static addFragment newInstance(){
        return new addFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        db = Room.databaseBuilder(requireContext(),
                        Database.class, "PeopleInfo")
                .build();

        dao = db.peopleDao();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding =FragmentAddBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Button saveBtn = binding.buttonSave;
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonSave(v);
            }
        });

    }
    public void buttonSave(View view){

        String fllName = binding.editTextFullName.getText().toString();
        String phoneNum = binding.editTextTelNo.getText().toString();
        String ClosenessD = binding.editTextClosenessDegree.getText().toString();

        PeopleInfo peopleInfo = new PeopleInfo(fllName,phoneNum,ClosenessD);


        mDisposable.add(dao.insert(peopleInfo)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(addFragment.this::handleResponse)
        );
    }
    private void handleResponse(){
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"Successfuly Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        binding.editTextFullName.setText("");
        binding.editTextTelNo.setText("");
        binding.editTextClosenessDegree.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        binding = null;
        mDisposable.clear();
    }
}
```

Show Fragment:

```
import ..

public class showFragment extends Fragment {
    PeopleAdapter peopleAdapter;
    List<PeopleInfo> arrayList;
    FragmentShowBinding binding;
    PeopleDao dao;
    Database database;
    private final CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    PageViewModel pageViewModel;


    public static showFragment newInstance() {
        return new showFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        database = Room.databaseBuilder(requireContext(),
                        Database.class, "PeopleInfo")
                .build();

        dao = database.peopleDao();


        getData();

        pageViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(PageViewModel.class);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentShowBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        pageViewModel.getAll().observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<List<PeopleInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<PeopleInfo> peopleInfos) {
                peopleAdapter.setData(peopleInfos);
                peopleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                getData();
            }
        });


    }


    public void getData() {

        compositeDisposable.add(dao.getAll()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(showFragment.this::handleResponce));

    }

    private void handleResponce(List<PeopleInfo> peopleInfoList){
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext()));

        peopleAdapter = new PeopleAdapter(peopleInfoList);
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(peopleAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        binding = null;
        compositeDisposable.clear();
    }
}
```

PeopleAdapter

```
public class PeopleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PeopleAdapter.viewHolder> {

    private List<PeopleInfo> peopleInfoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public PeopleAdapter(List<PeopleInfo> peopleInfoArrayList) {
        this.peopleInfoArrayList = peopleInfoArrayList;
    }

    public void setData(List<PeopleInfo> newData){
        peopleInfoArrayList.clear();
        peopleInfoArrayList.addAll(newData);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerRowBinding recyclerRowBinding = RecyclerRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),parent,false);
        return new viewHolder(recyclerRowBinding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.binding.fullNameTxt.setText(peopleInfoArrayList.get(position).fullName);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return peopleInfoArrayList.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private RecyclerRowBinding binding;
        public viewHolder(RecyclerRowBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }
    }
}
```

PageViewModel:

public class PageViewModel extends ViewModel {

```
private MutableLiveData<List<PeopleInfo>> pInfo = new MutableLiveData<>();

public LiveData<List<PeopleInfo>> getAll() {
    return pInfo;
}

public void setData(List<PeopleInfo> info){
    pInfo.setValue(info);
}
```

}

`

Comment: From where you are calling set method of your view model???
public void setData(List<PeopleInfo> info){
    pInfo.setValue(info);
}

Comment: Now I realized that I haven't used it anywhere. Where should I use it?

Comment: I add <list.add(peopleInfo);
        pageViewModel.setData(list);> that code bloke in saveButton from addFragment, and the problem has been resolved. I also removed the unnecessary setData method in the PeopleAdapter. Additionally, I deleted the excess code. thank you, have a good day